# How to wrap long function heads in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

How can I wrap a long function head in such a way that it can be considered "idiomatic" in Erlang?

I appreciate that this scenario is in itself a code smell, but I don't really have another option because I'm writing a fun to pass to *ets:fun2ms/1* and I don't want to have a line much longer than 80 characters. Here's the original function:

```
Matcher = ets:fun2ms(
    fun({Id, Orig2, _, Kg, _, _, Status}) when Orig1 == Orig2, Kg =< MaxKg, Status == pending ->
        {Id, Kg}
    end
)
```

What's the recommended way to wrap line #2?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

```
Matcher =
    ets:fun2ms(fun({Id, Orig2, _, Kg, _, _, Status})
                   when Orig1 == Orig2,
                        Kg =< MaxKg,
                        Status == pending ->
                            {Id, Kg}
                end)
```

Or

```
Selector = fun({Id, Orig2, _, Kg, _, _, Status})
               when Orig1 == Orig2,
                    Kg =< MaxKg,
                    Status == pending ->
                        {Id, Kg}
           end,
Matcher = ets:fun2ms(Selector)
```

Or whatever other way that makes the phrasing, and semantically distinct components if each phrase explicit and stand out in a way that is obvious and readable. The funky one is almost always the `end` at the end of a longish lambda -- and I've never found a satisfactory way to deal with that, other than to not write a lambda and instead write a top-level function.

If you have a *lot* of selection conditions (or modify one aspect of them at a time, such that declaring base functions, and then defining closures as lambdas above them makes sense), though, writing a module that is nothing but a library of selection conditions can sometimes simplify your code and prevent the weirdness of long lambdas and `end` entirely. You just have to decide what makes sense for you. Like they always say in Erland: First make it work, then make it beautiful. Only make it fast if you discover you have a problem, as "beautiful" usually takes care of the speed problem incidentally.

OTOH, there are mountains of virtually indecipherable inline lambda definitions in Erlang code (especially on GitHub), so its not like you're going outdo anyone in the ugly department (even if you make a few eyes bleed).

Comment: Thanks! Although the problem in this case is that *ets:fun2ms/1* requires the fun to be literally defined in the first argument, so I can't move the code to separate functions (meaning that Option 2 wouldn't work here).

Comment: Ah, that's right. One of those parse transforms... wee! Well, anyway, my advice was a bit more general than this particular case. Whenever I hit something like this I nearly always break the definition off by newlines as much as possible, especially with multiple guards. This is a syntactic wart in the same vein as certain cases you encounter with multiply-nested records. Luckily the rest of the language makes up for it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Most of your line length comes from guard functions. It's more idiomatic to use the function head:

```
Matcher = ets:fun2ms(
    fun({Id, Orig1, _, Kg, _, _, pending}) when Kg =< MaxKg ->
        {Id, Kg}
    end
)
```

I would generally avoid using equality in a guard, and I find the above more clear.